# Passing a user and password in a clickable URI link securely

Tags: web-services, http

I have a device that allows for remote control using something like this:

```
https://gooduser:secretpassword@www.example.com/webcallback?foo=bar
```

My question is, can I some how send an encrypted user/password so that end-users can't pull the username and password and login to the device?

My issue here is that I need these to be clickable links to send remote commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting your user nameand password in url, use HTML headers. Since you are calling https they will be encrypted. How you use it depends on your environment but using wget the command would be:

```
wget --user=gooduser --password=secretpassword https://www.example.com/webcallback?foo=bar
```

Comment: My issue here is that I need these to be clickable links.

Comment: @FrankThornton okay that's a different question... what language are you programming?

Comment: The page will be HTML but it can be generated by PHP

Comment: @FrankThornton okay create a new question asking scientifically this time what you want..